# Error message "You don't have permission to access without access log" when I submit form

Tags: php, forms, apache, web

I have a php website who is using apache 2.4 on windows server. In a specific page when I submit the form who goes to the same page it doesn't work and I have this

> 403

forbidden error message :

> "Forbidden You don't have permission to access
>   /cg60/abonnes/abonne/diverse/000000008528 on this server."

The problem doesn't appear to be **mod_security** because it doesn't seems to be available or enable either.
The other weird thing is that I don't have access log after submitting the form.

Here is my apache configuration

```
Listen 443
Listen 444

SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5

SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin


SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:c:/web/Apache/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "C:\web\www\Extranet\web"
ServerName extranet.mef-teleassistance.com
<Directory "C:\web\www\Extranet\web">
    AllowOverride All
    Options -Indexes        
    Options -Includes
    Options -ExecCGI
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from All
</Directory>

ErrorLog "c:/web/Apache/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "c:/web/Apache/logs/extranet.log"

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "C:/web/Apache/conf/ssl/crt/extranet.mef-teleassistance.com.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/web/Apache/conf/ssl/crt/extranet.mef-teleassistance.com.key"
SSLCertificateChainFile "C:/web/Apache/conf/ssl/crt/intermediate.crt"   

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "c:/web/Apache/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
```

Comment: We probably won't be able to help unless you post you form code and your htaccess file.

Comment: I can post the form code but unfortunatly it's a symfony2 form with a lot of embed form inside so it took a lot of place.
On the other side I can post the content of my apache configuration